# error_log message is truncated when using print_r

Tags: php

I'm not experienced in PHP and I'm, using:

```
error_log("big array:" . print_r($bigArray, true));
```

to look at what's inside a big array but it looks like the output is cut off before I get to the interesting stuff in the output like so:

```
...
           [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 100039235
                [start] => 11:00
                [end] => 19:00
                [punches] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 6319
                                [comment] =>
```

Is this expected? Are there other ways or workarounds to get more of the array logged out?

Comment: Can you provide an example? Are you sure it's not being limited by `error_log()`?

Comment: Probably a limitation of logger. Why not print the array at the interesting stuff?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you check the [error INI options in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) you'll notice there's a [`log_errors_max_len`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len) option:

> Set the maximum length of `log_errors` in bytes. In `error_log` information about the source is added. **The default is 1024 and 0 allows to not apply any maximum length at all**. This length is applied to logged errors, displayed errors and also to `$php_errormsg`.
>
> When an integer is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described in this FAQ, may also be used.

Hence, if you want to use `error_log` to output these huge messages, make sure you change `log_errors_max_len` to a large number (or `0` for unlimited length).

```
// Append to the start of your script
ini_set('log_errors_max_len', '0');
```

Comment: Seems reasonable! I posted another question about log_errors_max_len not working here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622760/changing-log-errors-max-len-has-no-effect  Maybe you can help me twice today :)

Comment: I suppose this answer was accurate at one time. But now `log_errors_max_len` does not change the limit for entries created via the `error_log()` function, as stated in the documentation, and pointed out in [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52100034/3303195).

Answer (score 21):

This answer is a bit out of date.

The output from `error_log` will still get truncated, even if `log_errors_max_len` is set to 0 (for unlimited output).

As per [the PHP documentation for log_errors_max_len](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len):

> This length is applied to logged errors, displayed errors and also to `$php_errormsg`, but not to explicitly called functions such as `error_log()`.

The only way to get your `error_log()` statements to truly output large amounts of information is to specify a custom log file.

```
error_log("big array:" . print_r($bigArray, true), 3, '/path/to/custom.log');
```

The second parameter (3) indicates the message type (external log) as per [the error_log documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).

Comment: This works perfectly, it MUST be the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

As scrowler mentions its error_log that's limiting the output.

The error_log will log to syslog by default and in your code, the length of which is limited by the runtime setting log_errors_max_len and which is 1024 by default.

See the following for further details on these functions and settings -

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php
http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len

What you probably want to do is just call print_r ($bigArray) to have it output directly, or if you want to see something a bit fancier in a browser use

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r ($bigArray, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Still truncated

Comment: [The max length limit can be easily increased](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors-max-len), which you almost linked.

Having errors included in the HTML output is not good practice.  How will you ever debug a layout issue with error output cluttering the content?  You never want this in a production environment.  I think it's a oversight that PHP has not deprecated the [`display-errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) `.ini` setting, and probably a mistake to even have it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If a string in the array contains a null character (byte with value zero), the output will also be truncated at that point.  From https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php#refsect1-function.error-log-notes:

> **Warning**  `error_log()` is not binary safe. `message` will be truncated by null character.

To work around this you could use `str_replace` to eliminate null characters:

```
error_log("big array:" . str_replace("\0", '\\0', print_r($bigArray, true)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can beat the system by calling `error_log` multiple times, since the character limit only seems to be applied to a single call:

```
function multiline_error_log($val) {
  $lines = preg_split("/[\r]?[\n]/", print_r($val, 1));
  foreach ($lines as $line) error_log($line);
}
```

This will work as long as no single textual line of the output of `print_r` exceeds the character limit. Note it may be worth incorporating Jake's answer into how you define `multiline_error_log` if you are worried about null character issues.

Comment: This is utter madness.  But I like it.  Actually could be useful.  Each error log line contains a date-time stamp at the start.  Many times that has got in the way of diffing logs.  Perhaps one for every line could help.