# changing log_errors_max_len has no effect

Tags: php

I'm **not** experienced in PHP and I had problems logging out big arrays using `error_log` and `print_r`.

I was told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621252/error-log-message-is-truncated-when-using-print-r) to change the `log_errors_max_len` of the php.ini file and I went ahead and did a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see where the php.ini file was loaded from. Then I changed it to `log_errors_max_len = 0` but still the output is truncated.

I'm also using Laravel.

Anybody has any idea why this is not working? (I already restarted apache :)

Comment: Could you define big arrays?

Comment: I'm not really sure how big it is since the output is not showing the full array. It is nested with at least 4 levels. See example output here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621252/error-log-message-is-truncated-when-using-print-r

Comment: What does a var_dump give you?

Comment: It crashes the "Manager" class (part of a rest api) and me tailing application log or the apache error log gives no output.

Comment: Let the var_dump stay and instead of running it in the browser run the script from (I'm guessing you use linux) linux terminal.

Comment: did your restarted the http service ?

Answer (score 6):

The main thing here, is that `log_errors_max_len` seems pretty useless in this situation. PHP manual states that:

> This length is applied to logged errors, displayed errors and also to
>   $php_errormsg, but **not to explicitly called functions such as
>   error_log()**

The only solution I was able to find so far is to use:

```
error_log("Long error message...", 3, CUSTOM_LOG_FILE);
```

The second parameter of `error_log()` allows you to redirect message to a custom file. So, the last parameter should be a path to a custom log file.

This way I'm getting full error message and, what might be more important for someone, non ASCII characters are clearly readable there (not sure though, might be my bad, but when I'm logging them with standard log file - I get things like `\xd0\xbf`).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the configuration at the top of your page like this.

```
<?php
ini_set("log_errors_max_len", 0);
?>
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966540/log-errors-max-len-1024-in-php-ini-but-php-log-keeps-growing). Might it be the issue you have?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was, I mixed up php script arguments and php interpreter arguments. This happened in an IDE, but could as well happen in command line.

Two different things:

```
php -d log_errors_max_len=0 index.php // Interpreter arguments
```

---

```
php index.php -d log_errors_max_len=0 // Script arguments
```

[image]